# Не получается получить доступ по ftp://

Tags: php

привет.У меня denwer и там можно использовать 2 хоста 'localhost' и 'test1.ru' .
Хочу получить доступ к 'test1.ru' с 'localhost' через ftp?Хочу создать там какую-нибудь папочку.

```
$ftp=ftp_connect("test1.ru");
ftp_mkdir($ftp,"test!!!");

ошибка
```

> **Warning: ftp_mkdir() expects
> parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
> given in
> W:\home\localhost\www\index.php on
> line 12**

```
Прошу помощи.
```

Comment: Пару дней назад работал тоже на денвере, но посоветовали поставить **Open Server**, поставил, теперь доволен как никогда. Поэтому, на вашем месте я б также сделал :)

Comment: *много я чего хочу, но мама спит и я молчу*

ftp_connect() вернул false, причина может быть во многом, сделайте

    $ftp=ftp_connect("test1.ru") or die("Не удалось установить соединение с $ftp_server ($php_errormsg)");

Comment: Ошибка Undefined variable: ftp_server

Comment: а извините, уберите $ftp_sever :)

Comment: А пользователь есть на ftp-сервере??